# OpenXML Headers

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a docx which I am processing using the OpenXML SDK.

The doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts property has 2 items in it, yet when I open the docx as a zip file, it has header1.xml up to header6.xml.  How can I access (and modify) all of these headers programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was a header which was not actually used in the document